# create dynamic Keyboard telegram bot in c# with keyboard button not inline button in c#

Tags: c#, keyboard, bots, telegram

How can I create a dynamic keyboard button I found some codes but they are for inline buttons?
I want to get data from database and create one button in each row with keyboard button

```
var keyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    new[] {
        new[]{
            new KeyboardButton("a"),
        },
        new[]{
            new KeyboardButton("b"),
        },
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn the very basics of the technology and the come back if you have any specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

The first part (i.e. adding the buttons from db) is OK with the same code you wrote.

The second part (i.e. changing button layout) I'm afraid, is not possible as far as I know. Because layout is done by Telegram app in client device and based on many things including device screen size and may change in different app versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `InlineKeyboardMarkup` and `InlineKeyboardButton` instead of it, you can refer to [this example](https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot.examples/blob/master/Telegram.Bot.Examples.Echo/Program.cs#L91-L103).

Please look up your library document next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static ReplyKeyboardMarkup calendarMenu;

SqlDataAdapter sc3 = new SqlDataAdapter("select KeyboardName from  dbo.Keyboards", SqlConnection);
DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
sc3.Fill(dt3);

int keyboardRows = 0;
if (dt3.Rows.Count % 2 == 0)
{
    keyboardRows = dt3.Rows.Count / 2;
}
else
{
    keyboardRows = (dt3.Rows.Count / 2) + 1;
}

KeyboardButton[][] kbc = new KeyboardButton[(keyboardRows + 1)][];

KeyboardButton[] keys = new KeyboardButton[dt3.Rows.Count];

var i = 0;
foreach (DataRow cn3 in dt3.Rows)
{
    keys[i] = new KeyboardButton(cn3["KeyboardName"].ToString());
    i++;
}

for (int r = 0, s = 0; r < keyboardRows; r++, s++)
{
    if (dt3.Rows.Count % 2 == 0)
    {
        kbc[r] = new KeyboardButton[] {keys[r + s], keys[r + s + 1]};
    }
    else
    {
        if ((r + s) != keys.Length)
        {
            kbc[r] = new KeyboardButton[] { keys[r + s], keys[r + s + 1] };
        }
        else
        {
            kbc[r] = new KeyboardButton[] { keys[r + s] };
        }
     }
 }

 kbc[keyboardRows] = new KeyboardButton[] { new KeyboardButton("Return to Main Menu"), };

 calendarMenu = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup
 {
     Keyboard = kbc
 };
```